# combining android components in a custom view

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-custom-view

I'm not sure where to start with this, I've been building an app over the last week and have made good progress and need a custom view now. I've looked at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html.
 but huh...not sure how to piece it together. 
I want to position the number picker to the left and some text and an image to the right and be able to listen for clicks on the number picker... To be honest I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a layout to combine your Components.  Define your layout in xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
       <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
        />
       <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/picker"
       android:src="..."
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
       />
      <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/text"
       android:text="some text"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

To use this layout as the rows of a list: create a custom list adapter that extends BaseAdapter, set your list adapter to your custom list adapter, and Override the getView method of the adapter with the below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = null;

    //if convertView is null, inflate a view.
    //otherwise reuse the convertView   
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.filebrowserrow, null);
    }
    else
    {
        view = convertView;
    }

    //retrieve picker to set listeners, initialize values, etc  
    NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker)view.findViewById(R.id.picker);

    //retrieve ImageView to change image, etc   
    ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);

    //retrieve TextView to change text, etc 
    TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);     

    return view;
```

}

Comment: I thought maybe of doing that but I'll need to create a list of these so I thought it might better to have a combined view...

Comment: i edited my answer to show how to use this layout as the rows of a list.

Comment: @ab11 This answers zcourts question, but I want to actually make a custom component. How can I do that? I want to combine button and progressbar.